# Bash - compare an argument with a digit

Tags: bash, if-statement, math

I am trying to compare two files by size and take actions depending on the ratio:

```
filesize_compressed=$(stat --format=%s "${BASE}_${suffix}.mp4")
filesize_original=$(stat --format=%s "${BASE}.mp4")
compression_ratio=$(echo "scale=2; ${filesize_original} / ${filesize_compressed}" | bc)
if [[ "${compression_ratio}" -lt "1.5" ]]; then
#do something
else
#do something else
fi
```

but keep getting this error:

```
[[: 1.5: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".5")
```

I tried to assign

```
compression_ratio_math=$("${compression_ratio}" | tr -cd '[[:digit:]]')
```

and use `compression_ratio_math` instead of `compression_ratio` but it did not work either.
I read every question with similar subject here but no suggested solution seemed to work for me.
Any ideas of what am I doing wrong?

Comment: afaik, bash only has integer arithmetic, so it doesn't know what to do with the `.5`.

Comment: You can scale your calculations.  For instance, multiply everything by 100, truncate any decimal portion, and compare the result with 150 instead of 1.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible work-around in `bash` with the help of `bc`:

```
#!/bin/bash

compression_ratio=1.499

if (( $(echo "${compression_ratio} < 1.5" | bc) )); then
    echo "less"
else
    echo "more"
fi
```

Echoing the comparison to `bc` should be able to then work with floating point numbers.

***EDIT***: possibly a nicer way to redirect to `bc`:

```
(( $(bc <<< "${compression_ratio} < 1.5") )) && echo "true" ; exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash is not capable of comparing point Numbers. However, there is a workaround with `awk`:

```sh
$num=1.5
if [ "y" = "$(echo | awk "(${compression_ratio} > $num) { print \"y\"; }")" ]; then
    # ... code...
fi
```

You can also use `bc` but that is not pre-installed on all un*x distributions.

Comment: Here is the error I get now: /home/user/Scripts/script.sh: line 182: 1.11: command not found
/home/user/Scripts/script.sh: line 183: =1.5: command not found
awk: cmd. line:1: (1.11 > ) { print "y"; }
awk: cmd. line:1:         ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: (1.11 > ) { print "y"; }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in bash, but since you're already using `bc`, you could directly use its comparison operator `<` that would give you 0 or 1.

Comment: `bc` is not pre-installed on all distributions.

Answer (score 0):

Without calling any external program

```
filesize_compressed=$(stat --format=%s "${BASE}_${suffix}.mp4")
filesize_original=$(stat --format=%s "${BASE}.mp4")

cr100=$(( filesize_original * 100 / filesize_compressed ))  #multiple with 100

if (( cr100 < 150 )); then   #use 150 instead of 1.5 (e.g. also multiple with 100)
#do something
else
#do something else
fi
```